# Automate daily downloading

Tags: python, python-2.7, download

Before I attempt to script this, I'm wondering if a program already exists.

Everyday I download openstreetmap data. The files are updated with the naming convention 'xxx.osc.gz' everyday the file gets 1 up'd ex. '001' to '002'.

I have only been able to find programs to help mirror or schedule downloading ( osmosis, or wget). I do not want the whole database everyday, just the newest file.

Any suggestions or point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: what OS/shell do you want to script this on?

Comment: Seeing as the filenames are zero-padded, do they roll over (ie 999 -> 000) or expand (999 -> 1000)?

Comment: There is a folder named 000 at file 999 the folder would be created 001, and file 001 would start in a new directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a YAML file with the latest changeset. Keep a record of your latest download, then use `urlretrieve` on that range.

```
import os, urllib, yaml


os_url = "http://planet.openstreetmap.org/replication/"
base_dir = "./"

try:
    with open('download.log', 'r') as f:
        last_set = int(f.readlines()[-1].strip())
except:
    last_set = int(raw_input("Enter latest set:"))

stream = urllib.urlopen(os_url+"changesets/state.yaml")
latest_set = yaml.load(stream)['sequence']


for seq in range(last_set+1,latest_set+1):
    changeset_dir = "changesets/000/%03d/"%(seq/1000)
    changeset_file = "%03d.osm.gz"%(seq%1000)
    remote_file = os_url + changeset_dir + changeset_file
    local_dir = base_dir + changeset_dir
    local_file = local_dir + changeset_file

    if not os.path.exists(local_dir):
        os.makedirs(local_dir)

    try:
        with open(local_file) as f: pass
        print "Already downloaded",seq
    except:
        urllib.urlretrieve(remote_file, local_file)
        print "Downloaded changeset",seq

print "Up-to-date"


with open('download.log', 'a') as f:
    f.write('%s\n'%latest_set)
```